# jQuery multiple click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm forced to use a script loaded from an external server.

This script basically adds an element `<div class="myClass">` and bind a `click` method to it.

The thing is, in the `click` function associated to the element, they have a `return false` statement at the end.

I also have my own script and I'm trying to add a `click` method to the same element using `$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function() { ... })`

My problem is that their event is triggered before and the `return false` in their function doesn't trigger my own `click` method.

I've tried loading my script before theirs but that didn't fix the problem.
I've read about unbinding and then rebinding but I'm not sure it's a good option since their code can change at any  moment.

Anything else I could try?

Comment: well one way is pass event as argument and use `event.preventDefault()` for your script.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I'm not sure I understand. Where would I pass this event?

Comment: could you try event namespace `$(document).on('click.namespace', '.myClass', function() { ... })?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that event delegation depends on the event bubbling up to the element that you bind the handler to. When their handler returns false, that prevents bubbling.

You'll have to bind the handler directly to the elements after they're added:

```
$(".myClass").click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I was trying to write less code with the .on method but it seems I can't. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your handler function return false.. it prevents the event from bubbling.

In your tag html you have to write something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myHandler(); return false;"></button>
```

Or if you use jQuery:

```
$(".btn").on('click', function (event){ 
    //do stuff..
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Although this is true, this was not what I asked but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just recently.  How I fixed it is, I added another class onto that element:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $(".myClass").addClass("myNewClass");
});
```

and than binded click events to that class like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".myNewClass", function () { ... });
```

This worked for me, as it overwrote the `myClass` class with the `myNewClass` click event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ... 
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onLoad why don't you add a new class to the myClass div and then set up a event listener for the new class.

```
$(".myClass").addClass("myClass2");

$(".myClass2").on('click', function() { ... })
```