# Reponsive Menu Js (clear dom?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to create a responsive menu for my website, however, I have a problem : I have two devices (desktop & mpbile phone) with the same HTML but two different JS. I share my problem in few line of code.

```
eventDesktop = function() {
  $('header').click(function() {
    console.log('Desktop');
  });
};
eventPhone = function() {
  $('header').click(function() {
    console.log('Phone');
  });
};
eventWitch = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
    eventDesktop();
  } else {
    eventPhone();
  }
};

eventWitch();

$(window).resize(function() {
  eventWitch();
});
```

So, after loading that's ok because only one is load, but after resize there are 2 fonctions for the same element, and I want to have only witch one i need. So here, i want to see on the console only 'Desktop' or 'Phone' but not the 2 both, when i click.

Thanks for reading.
If you have question i can specify my ask.

Greet.

Comment: also what this code does is , everytime `eventWitch` is called it will assign a new click event to the `header` element. so you will end up many click events for a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you creating 2 different Event-Handlers, so he is using both in your case.

Try to `.unbind()` them:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $( 'header' ).unbind( 'click' );
    eventWitch();
});
```

So **all** Click events will be removed, keep that in mind.

There is another method I didn't tried, but maybe it helps: [jQuery multiple click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649623/jquery-multiple-click-event)

As **andrea.spot** wrote: "*You need to make your handler function return false.. it prevents the event from bubbling.*"

Adding this to your code:

```
eventDesktop = function() {
    $('header').click(function() {
        console.log('Desktop');
        return false;
    });
};
eventPhone = function() {
    $('header').click(function() {
        console.log('Phone');
        return false;
    });
};
```

The last solution would be changing the way of thinking. This means do the Click-Handler and THAN check for the Windows Size. Currently you checking for the Window Size and than calling a Click-Handler, this will always lead to multible Click Handlers, but not if you create one handler and than do the statements.

My text to code:

```
eventWitch = function() {
    $( 'header' ).click( function(){
        if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
            console.log( 'Desktop' );
        } else {
            console.log( 'Mobile' );
        }
    }
};
```

Does one of this solutions works for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use your 1st solution, it's will be the best one for me, beacause it's doesn't change my structure. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are binding two events on same element on the resize of window. You could try this

```
$('header').click(function() {
 if(window.innerWidth > 480)
    console.log('Desktop');
 else
    console.log('Phone');
});
```

So, check everytime when user click on header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but for a clear code a use .unbind('click'). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
eventDesktop = function() {
    $('header').unbind('click').click(function() {// here it will removes all old click events assigned to this element.
        console.log('Desktop');
    });
};
eventPhone = function() {
    $('header').unbind('click').click(function() {// here it will removes all old click events assigned to this element.
        console.log('Phone');
    });
};
eventWitch = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
        eventDesktop();
    } else {
        eventPhone();
    }
};

eventWitch();

$(window).resize(function() {
    eventWitch();
});
```